# How do I install ImageMagick on mac os 14.0 Sonoma?

Tags: macos, image, imagemagick

So as Mac OS 14.0 Sonoma is still in beta the brew install command fails

```
brew install imagemagick
```

.
Is there a way to make it work?

`Warning: You are using macOS 14. We do not provide support for this pre-release version. It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this pre-release version. It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow. Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories. Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated. Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response. Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media. You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response. Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request. We will review it but may or may not accept it.`

I would like to know if this is terminant or someone was able to make it work :s

Comment: So no error messages? And the text you quote is clear: "You are on your own"...

Comment: As a workaround, install `docker` then you can do `docker run --it alpine:latest` and be in alpine within 2 seconds. Then you can do `apk update` and `apk add imagemagick` and you are all set.